# name 'sc' is not defined & Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark 2.2.0 from my jupyter notebook.
Sometimes it happens that while I'm using sc, for example here

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sparkContext=SQLContext(sc)
```

I'm getting an error

> NameError: name 'sc' is not defined

But if I modify my code by adding

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
```

I'm getting an error

> ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spark` is the object you want. Not `sc`.

The fact that you get an error means you need to **get** or create the session, which you already are.

```
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I'm not sure you need a `SQLContext`. `spark.sql()` or `spark.read()` are the dataset entry points.

First bullet here on [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-16-to-20)

> `SparkSession` is now the new entry point of Spark that replaces the old `SQLContext` and `HiveContext`

If you need an `sc` variable at all, that is `sc = spark.sparkContext`

Comment: Yes ,after adding sc = spark.sparkContext it is working. Thanks